# Optaplanner throws exception with pillarmove with filterClass

Tags: java, optaplanner

I've configured pillarMove in my application as:

```
<pillarChangeMoveSelector>
                <pillarSelector>
                    <entitySelector>
                        <entityClass>com.X.Y.Z.MyEntity</entityClass>
                        <cacheType>STEP</cacheType>
                    </entitySelector>
                    <subPillarEnabled>true</subPillarEnabled>
                    <minimumSubPillarSize>1</minimumSubPillarSize>
                    <maximumSubPillarSize>40</maximumSubPillarSize>
                </pillarSelector>
                <valueSelector variableName="variable">
                </valueSelector>
                <filterClass>com.X.Y.Z.MyEntityPillarMoveFilter</filterClass>
            </pillarChangeMoveSelector>
```

but it throws exception

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The selector
>   (DefaultPillarSelector(FromSolutionEntitySelector(MyEntity))) with
>   randomSelection  (true) and subPillarEnabled (true) does not support
>   getSize() because the number of sub pillars scales exponentially.     at
>   org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.entity.pillar.DefaultPillarSelector.getSize(DefaultPillarSelector.java:180)
>     at
>   org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.generic.PillarChangeMoveSelector.getSize(PillarChangeMoveSelector.java:73)
>     at
>   org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.decorator.FilteringMoveSelector.determineBailOutSize(FilteringMoveSelector.java:119)
>     at
>   org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.decorator.FilteringMoveSelector.iterator(FilteringMoveSelector.java:78)
>     at
>   org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.composite.UnionMoveSelector$RandomUnionMoveIterator.(UnionMoveSelector.java:144)
>     at
>   org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.composite.UnionMoveSelector.iterator(UnionMoveSelector.java:129)

PillarMove is not much useful without filter as it'll select all of entities. In contrast, subPillar enabled with no filter also does not help much in my use case.

Does optaplanner support pillarMove with filterClass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not supported currently.

This is due to a more general issue in at least until 7.6.0.Final: Selection filtering's bailOut calculation uses the `getSize()` which isn't always supported (it's impossible to support for pillar moves).

Comment: I've created a JIRA for it https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-934. However, I think I should make a custom pillar move and then I can have it filtered in isMoveDoable(). What do you think?